# No view found for id ... for fragment in a Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog

I want show 2 tabs in a custom `Dialog` in an `Activity`, but I am getting the following error.

Error:

```
No view found for id 0x7f0f0134 (com.hiro.chatio:id/viewPage_theme) for fragment
    PostColorPickerFragment{35ffefce #0 id=0x7f0f0134 android:switcher:2131689780:0}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f0134 (com.hiro.chatio:id/viewPage_theme)
    for fragment PostColorPickerFragment{35ffefce #0 id=0x7f0f0134 android:switcher:2131689780:0}
```

`MainActivity`:

```
private Button pick_color;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_blog); 

    pick_color = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_blog_color_btn);

    pick_color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CreateBlogActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.blog_theme_picker);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.SlideUpDialogAnimation;

            Button pickColor = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pick_color_btn);
            Button default_color = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.default_color);

            TabLayout mTabLayout = (TabLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_theme);

            CustomViewPager mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) dialog.findViewById(R.id.viewPage_theme);

            ThemePagerAdapter mThemePagerAdapter = new ThemePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            mViewPager.setAdapter(mThemePagerAdapter);
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

            mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

            mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager); }); }
```

`ThemePagerAdapter`:

```
public class ThemePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public ThemePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            PostColorPickerFragment postColorPickerFragment = new PostColorPickerFragment();
            return postColorPickerFragment;

        case 1:
            PostThemePickerFragment postThemePickerFragment = new PostThemePickerFragment();
            return postThemePickerFragment;

        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            return "Color";
        case 1:
            return "Theme";
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

`PostThemePickerFragment`:

```
public class PostThemePickerFragment extends Fragment {

public PostThemePickerFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_theme_picker, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: where is `PostColorPickerFragment` code?

Comment: Instead of just a `Dialog`, you'll have to use a `DialogFragment` - and its child `FragmentManager` - to get that `ViewPager` to work. The `Activity`'s `FragmentManager` won't be able to find anything in a `Dialog`, since it's not attached to the `Activity`'s hierarchy.

Comment: Mike M. is right. You have to use `DialogFragment` instead of `Dialog`.

Comment: how can I set custom view for DialogFragment

Comment: @MikeM. can you write some code to replace Dialog by DialogFragment ? I want when I click button, dialog will show custom layout tablayout with 2 fragment.

Comment: Sure, I can put something together. Gimme a minute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting that Exception because the `Activity`'s `FragmentManager` cannot find `View`s in a `Dialog`, as its layout is not attached to the `Activity`'s hierarchy.  In order to use `Fragment`s in a `Dialog`, you'll have to use a `DialogFragment`, passing its child `FragmentManager` to the `PagerAdapter` to handle the transactions.

As with any regular `Fragment`, we can inflate the layout in `onCreateView()`, and set it up in `onViewCreated()`. We'll also override the `onCreateDialog()` method to modify the window settings there.

```
public class ThemeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public ThemeDialogFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.blog_theme_picker, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button pickColor = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.pick_color_btn);
        Button default_color = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.default_color);
        TabLayout mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_theme);
        CustomViewPager mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPage_theme);

        ThemePagerAdapter mThemePagerAdapter = new ThemePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mThemePagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog d = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        d.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.SlideUpDialogAnimation;
        d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return d;
    }
}
```

You can see that everything you had in the `onClick()` method is now handled in the `DialogFragment`, and that method becomes simply:

```
pick_color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new ThemeDialogFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "theme");
        }
    }
);
```