# Show tablayout in alert dialogue

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-tablayout

I am trying to show a tablayout in an alertdialog.
I am getting errors about not finding views 
I tried the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779665/no-view-found-for-id-for-fragment-in-a-dialog).
It still does not work.
I have two simple fragments and the rest is here:

Adapter:

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm, FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                RegistrationFragment()
            }
            else -> {
                return LoginFragment()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> "Registration"
            else -> {
                return "Login"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

class extending DialogueFragment:

```
class MeDialog : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_registration, container)

    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         val mTabLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.tabs_main) as TabLayout
        val mViewPager = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.viewpager_main) as ViewPager

        val mThemePagerAdapter = MyPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)

        mViewPager.adapter = mThemePagerAdapter
        mViewPager.currentItem = 0

        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager)
    }


}
```

I am calling it this way:

```
  MeDialog().show(supportFragmentManager, MeDialog::class.java.simpleName)
```

The error I get is:

```
No view found for id 0x7f09015d (app.com:id/viewpager_main) for fragment
```

How do I make it work.

Login_resgistration xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabs_main" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Does `login_registration` indeed contain a view with an id of `viewpager_main`?

Comment: yes all that is fine

Comment: I added it......

Answer (score 0):

You can display a Custom dialog using Dialog class. [see here how to display Custom dialog](https://11zon.com/android/android_customdialog.php)
then you can easily display [TabLayout](https://11zon.com/android/android_tablayout.php) in Dialog.

Comment: I do this most of the time but showing the tabs has been somewhat of a hassle