# No view found for id viewpager ( ScaleFragment )

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-activity

Hello i have a seettings popup in my project 
and this popup has a view pager
i tried a lot of thing but always give this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a013c (com.intek.posseal:id/settingsViewPager) for fragment ScaleFragment{1d3a04f (060fd7e7-c91b-4c15-876b-b19c5c26cec1) id=0x7f0a013c}

my view pager adapter here is

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter
import com.intek.posseal.Activities.Settings.ScaleFragment

class SettingPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getItem(i: Int): Fragment {
        return ScaleFragment()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int  = 1
}
```

and here is my popup code

```
fun configurePopup(context: PosActivity) {
        val myDialog = Dialog(context)
        myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_settings)
        myDialog.setCancelable(false)
        myDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        myDialog.window!!.attributes.windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation
        myDialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

        val btnLogOut = myDialog.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.popupLogOut)
        val imgSave = myDialog.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imgSave)
        val gvMenus = myDialog.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.gvMenus)
        pager = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.settingsViewPager)
        pager!!.adapter = SettingPagerAdapter(context.supportFragmentManager)
        myDialog.show()
        }
```

and my fragment

```
import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.Window
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.intek.posseal.Data.Models.BaudRates
import com.intek.posseal.Data.Models.DataSize
import com.intek.posseal.Data.Models.Parity
import com.intek.posseal.Data.Models.Scales
import com.intek.posseal.Data.Repositories.SettingRepository
import com.intek.posseal.Helpers.PortHelper
import com.intek.posseal.Popups.SettingsPopup.Companion.settings
import com.intek.posseal.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_scale.*

class ScaleFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _settingRepository = SettingRepository()
    private var ports = ArrayList<String>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scale, container, false)
    }
}
```

how can i solve this issue what you offer ?

Comment: You cannot use a `ViewPager` with `Fragment`s in a plain `Dialog`. You would need to use a `DialogFragment`, and pass that `DialogFragment`'s `childFragmentManager` to the `PagerAdapter`. Otherwise, just use plain `View`s with your `ViewPager`. I would also mention that it's kinda pointless to use a `ViewPager` if you're only going to have one page.

Comment: any example can you suggest ?

Comment: Not in Kotlin, but I've a pretty simple one in Java in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45781252). It should be easily translatable. As I mentioned, though, if you're only going to have one page, the `ViewPager` is rather pointless. It'd be much simpler to just make `ScaleFragment` into a `DialogFragment` itself.